# My python program has an indentation error

Tags: python, indentation

I was trying to code a basic program but when I tried to run it I got the error `IndentationError: expected an indented block` and I can't figure out which part I didn't indent.  Here is the code:

```
from os import system
from time import sleep

while True:
input = raw_input("How are you doing?")
if input == "good":
    print "That's great!"
    sleep(3)
elif input == "bad":
    print "How come?"
    sleep(3)
else:
    print "What?
    sleep(3)
```

It's done with the latest version of python2.  If you could help that'd be great.

Comment: inside of `while` should be indented. Also, you are missing quotation mark on last print statement.

Comment: You need to indent after `while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from os import system
from time import sleep

while True:
   input = raw_input("How are you doing?")
   if input == "good":
      print "That's great!"
      sleep(3)
   elif input == "bad":
      print "How come?"
      sleep(3)
   else:
      print "What?"
      sleep(3)
```

Edit: You need to indent the while loop. And add a quotation in the last print statement.